# Precedence of post increment

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Can anyone explain what will be the output of following code and why?

```
int main()
{
   int i[] = {3, 5};
   int* p = i;

   int j = --*p++;

   printf("%d\n%d\n", j,*p);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? What is the output if you run the program?

Comment: Try it and see, it will help more than asking someone else to do it and tell you what happens.

Comment: `system("pause");` will emit "Press any key to continue . . ." in a Windows or DOS environment – possibly with localized text – because it will execute the command interpreter's local `pause`. And it will do so because you asked it to. On other OS'es, most likely *all* of them, you will get an error.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer:  "Just run it and see what happens" is almost universally bad advice when it comes to C.  There's too much code that will build and run and give a totally meaningless result.

Comment: `--*p++` is parsed as `--(*(p++))`.  The *result* of the expression is the current value of the thing `p` points to (`i[0]`) minus 1.  The *side effect* is to decrement the thing `p` points to and advance `p` to point to the next object.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer He mainly Want to ask why.

Comment: @SurajJain An intermediate skill level question about operator precedence and order of evaluation? Certainly not a newbie tutorial. Order of evaluation and sequence points are not beginner-level topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually going to answer this question, even though it's true that "the OP simply needs to compile the code and run it", because it isn't obvious to a beginner that this *is* one of the cases where that gives the right answer.  People get dinged all the time on this site for asking why superficially similar code (that *does* have undefined behavior) gives a surprising answer.

```
int j = --*p++;
```

means

```
int j = *p - 1;
*p = j;
p += 1;
```

That is, `*p` (the value that `p` *points to*) is decremented, the decremented value is written to `j`, and then `p` itself is incremented.

There is no undefined behavior here because the `--` and `++` operators in the original form are acting on *two different data objects*.  The expressions that have undefined behavior due to multiple use of the side-effect operators all involve modifying the *same data object* twice in the same expression ("without an intervening sequence point").

(If you're wondering *why* the `--` applies to `*p` but the `++` applies only to `p`, the answer is "because that's what the grammar of the language says.  Sorry, this is just one of those things you have to memorize.")